# Issue with building a webhook for dialogflow

Tags: python, json, webhooks, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I was trying to develop a google assistant action using dialogflow. I ran into some trouble while developing the webhook. I am using python. Here is the code:

```
import json
import os
import urllib
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response
app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/webhook',methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    req = request.get_json(silent=True,force=True)
    print("Request:")
    print(json.dumps(req,indent=4))
    res={
        "speech": "Complete",
        "displayText": "Complete",
        "source": "Myself"
    }
    res=json.dumps(res,indent=4)
    r=make_response(res)
    r.headers['Content-Type']='application/json'
    return r

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port=int(os.getenv('PORT',8080))
    app.run(port=port,host='localhost',ssl_context='adhoc')
```

The issue is that the JSON object returned by the script is always empty.
Using ngrok, I got something like this in the fulfillment key of the object:

```
"fulfillment": {
        "speech": "",
        "messages": []
    }
```

and I am not able to figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should not change the title of your post using solved, what you should do is: if an answer helps you solve your problem then you should mark it as correct, if you have your own answer then create one and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

base_response = {
                 'speech':"sample response",

                 'source' : 'Manual'}


@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        text = """WELCOME to RBG<br>
        /testing -> red testing<br>"""
        return text
    else:
        req_body = request.get_json()
        print(req_body)
        response = base_response.copy()
        return jsonify(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=True)
```

This worked for me. Hope this helps. I used ngrok too from my raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

Changline these lines:

```
port=int(os.getenv('PORT',8080)
app.run(port=port,host='localhost',ssl_context)
```

To

```
app.run(port=8080,host='localhost')
```

Solved the issue for me.